# Как лучше объяснить постановку запятой перед союзом И?

Tags: синтаксис

(1) **Возвращалась** она домой каждый день под утро **и ложилась** в гостиной на полу, **и потом рассказывала** всем трогательно, как она спит под цветами.

(2) А Аня всё **каталась** на тройках, **ездила** с Артыновым на охоту, **играла** в одноактных пьесах, **ужинала**, и всё реже и реже **бывала** у своих.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С точки зрения современной пунктуации только как присоединение. Видимо, Чехов разделил предложения на 2 части по  общности мысли.

(1) Возвращалась она домой каждый день под утро и ложилась в гостиной на полу//, и потом рассказывала всем трогательно, как она спит под цветами.

(2) А Аня всё каталась на тройках, ездила с Артыновым на охоту, играла в одноактных пьесах, ужинала,// и всё реже и реже бывала у своих.

Comment: Розенталь использует термин присоединительный союз в похожих предложениях, например: [Лизавета Ивановна] разливала чай, и получала выговоры за лишний расход сахара; она вслух читала романы, и виновата была во всех ошибках автора; она сопровождала графиню в её прогулках, и отвечала за погоду и за мостовую. Но здесь скорее сопоставление, а не присоединение.

Comment: В приведенных в вопросе примерах нет семантической спаянности между частями предложения, в них рассматриваются разные ситуации. Это тот случай, когда мы имеем нечто среднее между однородными членами и сложным предложением, поэтому пауза и запятая. В первом предложении хотя бы наречие разделяет их, а во втором и того нет. Интересно, можно поставить  тире (по образцу: Скакун мой призадумался — и прыгнул)?